# How to make a selected radio button change the text of a label

Tags: c++, events, radio-button

I'm currently making a program and I'm trying to make it so that when they select a radio button
it changes a label to the name of what they selected for example the display is here
Weapon> NONE SIGHT> NONE Barrel> NONE
Then I select a radio button called AK it displays
Weapon> AK SIGHT> NONE Barrel> NONE
Anyone know how to do so in c++?

Comment: It depends entirely upon what OS/UI framework/etc you are using and that information is not specified in your question.

Comment: Please show a [mre]